# NiFi ReplaceText Regex replace Newline with CRLF

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I have a textfile (GetFile-processor) with Unix-style Newline (\n), but need a Windows-style Carriage-Return+LineFeed CRLF (\r\n) in my FlowFile

My ReplaceText-Processor is working

```
Search value: ((?<!\x0d)\x0a|\x0d(?!\x0a))
Replacement value: ${literal(''):replaceFirst('','\r')}${literal(''):replaceFirst('','\n')}
```

Question:
my RegEx seems to me very complex
Do you know an easier way to convert in a FlowFile the \n to \r\n?

Have a nice weekend

Frank

Comment: Why in search value you don't have an expression just  for `\n` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file contains `\n` only, I see no reason to match `\r` with the pattern.

Use

```java
(?<!\r)\n
```

Replace with `${literal('\r\n')}`.

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \r                       '\r' (carriage return)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
```

Comment: Hi Ryszard,
thanks, it works with:
${literal('\r\n')}